# Maven add dependency on Spring 3.1.1 even it is not on in pom.xml

Tags: java, maven, war

I have problem that maven add dependency Spring 3.1.1 into war even it is not into pom. Also it isnt into dependency:tree

Here is my dependency:tree

```
PS C:\Users\pkostrou\IdeaProjects\cas-3.0.10.0> C:\Apps\apache-maven-3.8.6\bin\mvn.cmd dependency:tree
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for com.dhl.cas:cas:war:3.0.10.0
[WARNING] 'dependencies.dependency.(groupId:artifactId:type:classifier)' must be unique: org.springframework:spring-test:jar -> version (?) vs ${spring.framework.v
ersion} @ line 334, column 21
[WARNING]
[WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
[WARNING]
[WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
[WARNING]
[WARNING] The project com.dhl.cas:cas:war:3.0.10.0 uses prerequisites which is only intended for maven-plugin projects but not for non maven-plugin projects. For s
uch purposes you should use the maven-enforcer-plugin. See https://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/requireMavenVersion.html
[INFO] 
[INFO] --------------------------< com.dhl.cas:cas >---------------------------
[INFO] Building cas 3.0.10.0                                                   
[INFO] --------------------------------[ war ]---------------------------------
[WARNING] The POM for commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.9 is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, enable debug logging for more details
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ cas ---
[INFO] com.dhl.cas:cas:war:3.0.10.0
[INFO] +- com.dhl.resp:authentication-core:jar:1.0.9.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:4.2.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.ldap:spring-ldap-core:jar:1.3.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.json:json:jar:20090211:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.microsoft.azure:adal4j:jar:1.1.1:compile
[INFO] |     +- com.nimbusds:oauth2-oidc-sdk:jar:4.5:compile
[INFO] |     |  +- javax.mail:mail:jar:1.4.1:compile
[INFO] |     |  |  \- javax.activation:activation:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] |     |  +- net.jcip:jcip-annotations:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |     |  +- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.3.1:compile
[INFO] |     |  +- net.minidev:json-smart:jar:1.1.1:compile
[INFO] |     |  +- com.nimbusds:lang-tag:jar:1.4:compile
[INFO] |     |  \- com.nimbusds:nimbus-jose-jwt:jar:3.1.2:compile
[INFO] |     |     \- org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on:jar:1.51:compile
[INFO] |     \- com.google.code.gson:gson:jar:2.2.4:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:5.2.22.RELEASE:test
[INFO] +- junit:junit:jar:4.8.2:test
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:4.1.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.7:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction:jboss-transaction-api_1.1_spec:jar:1.0.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.0-api:jar:1.0.1.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.1.0.CR2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.15.0-GA:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:4.0.1.Final:compile
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:jar:4.1.0.Final:compile
[INFO] +- org.jasig.cas:cas-server-webapp:war:3.5.0:compile
[INFO] +- com.github.inspektr:inspektr-audit:jar:1.0.7.GA:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.aspectj:aspectjrt:jar:1.6.9:compile
[INFO] +- com.github.inspektr:inspektr-common:jar:1.0.7.GA:compile
[INFO] +- com.github.inspektr:inspektr-support-spring:jar:1.0.7.GA:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.github.inspektr:inspektr-error:jar:1.0.7.GA:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-cas:jar:4.2.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jasig.cas.client:cas-client-core:jar:3.4.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:jar:4.2.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:jar:4.2.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- javax.servlet:servlet-api:jar:2.5:provided
[INFO] +- jstl:jstl:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] +- commons-dbcp:commons-dbcp:jar:1.4:runtime
[INFO] |  \- commons-pool:commons-pool:jar:1.5.4:runtime
[INFO] +- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:1.0.0.GA:compile
[INFO] +- com.oracle:ojdbc7:jar:12.1.0.1.0:runtime
[INFO] +- org.hsqldb:hsqldb:jar:2.2.9:test
[INFO] +- net.sf.opencsv:opencsv:jar:2.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.jasig.cas:cas-server-core:jar:3.5.0:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.jasig.service:person-directory-impl:jar:1.5.0-RC6:provided
[INFO] |  |  +- com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:jar:2.1.12:provided
[INFO] |  |  |  \- javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:jar:2.1:provided
[INFO] |  |  |     \- javax.xml.stream:stax-api:jar:1.0-2:provided
[INFO] |  |  \- org.jasig.service:person-directory-api:jar:1.5.0-RC6:provided
[INFO] |  +- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- jdom:jdom:jar:1.0:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.santuario:xmlsec:jar:1.4.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.xml:xmldsig:jar:1.0:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.perf4j:perf4j:jar:log4jonly:0.9.14:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.webflow:spring-webflow:jar:2.3.0.RELEASE:provided
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.webflow:spring-binding:jar:2.3.0.RELEASE:provided
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework.webflow:spring-js:jar:2.3.0.RELEASE:provided
[INFO] |  |     \- org.springframework.webflow:spring-js-resources:jar:2.3.0.RELEASE:provided
[INFO] |  +- commons-jexl:commons-jexl:jar:1.1:provided
[INFO] |  +- commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.0:provided
[INFO] |  \- org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:jar:1.6.9:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:5.2.22.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:5.2.22.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:5.2.22.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-jcl:jar:5.2.22.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:5.2.22.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:5.2.22.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:5.2.22.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:5.2.22.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-aspects:jar:5.2.22.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-jms:jar:5.2.22.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-messaging:jar:5.2.22.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:5.2.22.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-context-support:jar:5.2.22.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:5.2.22.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:jar:4.2.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.security.extensions:spring-security-saml2-core:jar:1.0.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.opensaml:opensaml:jar:2.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.opensaml:openws:jar:1.5.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.opensaml:xmltooling:jar:1.4.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15:jar:1.46:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- ca.juliusdavies:not-yet-commons-ssl:jar:0.3.9:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- commons-httpclient:commons-httpclient:jar:3.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.velocity:velocity:jar:1.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.owasp.esapi:esapi:jar:2.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- xerces:xercesImpl:jar:2.10.0:runtime
[INFO] |  |  +- xalan:serializer:jar:2.7.1:runtime
[INFO] |  |  +- xml-resolver:xml-resolver:jar:1.2:runtime
[INFO] |  |  \- xalan:xalan:jar:2.7.1:runtime
[INFO] |  \- xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.4.01:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.4:compile
[INFO] |  \- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.2:compile
```

Here is my pom.xml :

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.dhl.cas</groupId>
    <artifactId>cas</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>cas</name>
    <version>3.0.10.0</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.cleverlance.dhl.spc</groupId>
        <artifactId>spc-parent</artifactId>
        <version>0.3</version>
    </parent>

    <scm>
        <developerConnection>scm:svn:https://teamforge.dhl.com/svn/repos/SPL_APPL_TOOLBOX/cas-server/src/tags/cas-3.0.10.0</developerConnection>
        <connection>scm:svn:https://teamforge.dhl.com/svn/repos/SPL_APPL_TOOLBOX/cas-server/src/tags/cas-3.0.10.0</connection>
        <url>https://teamforge.dhl.com/svn/repos/SPL_APPL_TOOLBOX/cas-server/src/tags/cas-3.0.10.0</url>
    </scm>

    <prerequisites>
        <maven>3.0.4</maven>
    </prerequisites>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <hibernate.version>4.1.0.Final</hibernate.version>
        <spring.version>4.2.3.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <spring.framework.version>5.2.22.RELEASE</spring.framework.version>
        <cas.version>3.5.0</cas.version>
        <netbeans.hint.deploy.server>Tomcat</netbeans.hint.deploy.server>
        <ojdbc7>12.1.0.1.0</ojdbc7>
        <authentication.core.version>1.0.9.0</authentication.core.version>
        <mysql.connector.version>5.1.44</mysql.connector.version>
    </properties>

 <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <filtering>false</filtering>
                <directory>${basedir}/src/main/java</directory>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
                <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>dct.properties</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <filtering>false</filtering>
                <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
            </resource>
        </resources>

        <testResources>
            <testResource>
                <filtering>false</filtering>
                <directory>${basedir}/src/test/resources</directory>
            </testResource>
        </testResources>

        <plugins>
        
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.9.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <sourcepath>${basedir}/dummy</sourcepath>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
                
                <!-- add src/main/generated for maven -->
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.7</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>add-source</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <sources>
                                    <source>src/main/generated</source>
                                </sources>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
        </plugins>


        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>

                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <version>2.0.2</version>
                    <inherited>true</inherited>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>1.6</source>
                        <target>1.6</target>
                        <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.1.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <warName>cas</warName>
                        <webResources>
                            <resource>
                                <directory>${basedir}/src/main/webapp</directory>
                                <filtering>true</filtering>
                            </resource>
                        </webResources>
                        <nonFilteredFileExtensions>
                            <nonFilteredFileExtension>xls</nonFilteredFileExtension>
                        </nonFilteredFileExtensions>
                        
           
                        <overlays>
                            <overlay>
                                <groupId>org.jasig.cas</groupId>
                                <artifactId>cas-server-webapp</artifactId>
                                <excludes>
<!--                                    <exclude>**/spring-configuration,**/unused-spring-configuration,**/cas-servlet.xml</exclude> -->
                                    <exclude>WEB-INF/unused-spring-configuration/**</exclude>
                                    <exclude>WEB-INF/spring-configuration/**</exclude>
                                    <exclude>**/cas-servlet.xml</exclude>
                                    <exclude>**/deployerConfigContext.xml</exclude>
                                    <exclude>**/login-webflow.xml</exclude>
                                    <exclude>**/log4j.xml</exclude>
                                </excludes>

                            </overlay>
                        </overlays>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>

                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.9</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <argLine>-Duser.timezone=Etc/GMT</argLine>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>

<!--                <plugin> -->
<!--                    <groupId> org.jasig.cas</groupId> -->
<!--                    <artifactId>cas-server-webapp</artifactId> -->
<!--                    <configuration> -->
<!--                        <skip>true</skip> -->
<!--                    </configuration> -->
<!--                </plugin> -->


            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.dhl.resp</groupId>
            <artifactId>authentication-core</artifactId>
            <version>${authentication.core.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- test -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        
        
        <!-- hibernate -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- CAS SSO -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jasig.cas</groupId>
            <artifactId>cas-server-webapp</artifactId>
            <type>war</type>

        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.inspektr</groupId>
            <artifactId>inspektr-audit</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.7.GA</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.inspektr</groupId>
            <artifactId>inspektr-common</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.7.GA</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.inspektr</groupId>
            <artifactId>inspektr-support-spring</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.7.GA</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-cas</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JSP -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <!-- database -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
             <version>1.4</version>
             <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- oracle driver -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc7</artifactId>
            <version>${ojdbc7}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency> 

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
            <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.9</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- tools -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.opencsv</groupId>
            <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- SAML -->
         <dependency>
             <groupId>org.jasig.cas</groupId>
             <artifactId>cas-server-core</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.opensaml</groupId>
                    <artifactId>opensaml</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
         </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jms</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security.extensions</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-saml2-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
 
        <!-- http client utils -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.4</version>
        </dependency>
 

    </dependencies>

    <distributionManagement>
        <repository>
            <id>releases</id>
            <url>http://czcholstc000112.prg-dc.dhl.com:8272/nexus/content/repositories/releases</url>
        </repository>
        <snapshotRepository>
            <id>snapshots</id>
            <url>http://czcholstc000112.prg-dc.dhl.com:8272/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
        </snapshotRepository>
    </distributionManagement>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
            <id>central</id>
            <name>maven-release</name>
            <url>https://artifactory.dhl.com/maven-release</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <snapshots/>
            <id>snapshots</id>
            <name>maven-snapshot</name>
            <url>https://artifactory.dhl.com/maven-snapshot</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>mysql</id>
            <dependencies>
                <!-- mysql driver -->
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
                    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
                    <version>${mysql.connector.version}</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

Can someone give me a point how to exclude Spring 3.1.1 from my war? I realy havent idea why Spring 3.1.1 is present into war.Thank you for help

Comment: What do you mean by "Spring 3.1.1" precisely? Spring is many things, but there is no artifact "spring". `spring-core`? Something else?

Comment: Yes, I mean spring-core.

Comment: Your project directly depends on spring-core 5.2.22, so it's not possible for Maven to resolve 3.1.1. How is your WAR created? This POM contains no assembly plugin, no spring boot maven plugin, no shade plugin. Those are the 3 most common ways to create a JAR/WAR.